# C# equivalent for C code needed

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

Can anybody tell me the C# equivalent for this C code?

```
static const value_string  message_id[] = {

  {0x0000, "Foo"},
  {0x0001, "Bar"},
  {0x0002, "Fubar"},
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private static readonly IDictionary<int, string> message_id = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            { 0x0000, "Foo" }, 
            { 0x0001, "Bar" }
        };
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public Enum MessageID { Foo = 0, Bar = 1, Fubar = 2 };
```

Then you can get the "string" version using `Enum.Format()` or `ToString()`.

Comment: I actually like bdukes solution even better, but that is because I need the data in a dictionary anyway.

Comment: No problem.  It just looked like something I would use an enum for -- absent any other context.  You might also want to consider loading it from a config file rather than defining it in code.  That way you wouldn't have to recompile your app to add another message id.

Comment: I know; but in my case I can safely hardcode it because I'm "dissecting" a protocol which doesn't change. If it does, I need to modify more than just the consts ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
MessageId[] messageIds = new MessageId[] {
    new MessageId(0x0000, "Foo"),
    new MessageId(0x0001, "Bar"),
    new MessageId(0x0002, "Fubar"),
    ...
};
```

(Where you define an appropriate `MessageId` constructor.)

That's the closest equivalent to the C code - but you should certainly consider whether an enum as per tvanfosson's answer might be a more appropriate design choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
private const value_string message_id[] = {

  new value_string() { prop1 = 0x0000, prop2 = "Foo"},
  new value_string() { prop1 = 0x0001, prop2 = "Bar"},
  new value_string() { prop1 = 0x0002, prop2 = "Fubar"},
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

or better yet, if you are using it like a dictionary:

```
private const Dictionary<string, int> message_id = {

   {"Foo", 0},
   {"Bar", 1},
   {"Fubar", 2},
   ...
}
```

in which the string is your key to the value.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be an exact match. C# does not allow `static` on `const` fields in classes. You can use `readonly`, though.

If you're using this in local scope, then you can get the benefit of anonymous typing and do this:

```
var identifierList = new[] {
    new MessageIdentifier(0x0000, "Foo"),
    new MessageIdentifier(0x0001, "Bar"),
    new MessageIdentifier(0x0002, "Fubar"),
    ...
};
```

I like [**this solution**](http://#662854) better, though.